# Stuck at chapter 5: I can't target the billboard!

Tags: remember-me

I'm on chapter 5 and have run into a glitch I think. The first thing you should do is target a billboard with your *Forcespammer*, but I can't do that. Nilin just streches her arm out and pulls it back instantly as if there is nothing to target there at all. I've watched a walkthrough video and I'm standing at the same spot but it doesn't work for me. I've tried both reloading and restarting the game.

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Try to pay attention to the tags you use.  The glitch tag is a game, not a bug/glitch type tag.

Comment: Restart from checkpoint/restart chapter?

Comment: [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4rVtNXPmCQ#t=2m30s) is one such video.  There is a comment from someone claiming to have the same problem (assuming that's not you).  So, it is probably a bug.  Have you tried restarting the chapter?

Comment: Same happened to me, reloading checkpoint doesn't help. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It just occured on my gameplay. I started running back and forth while clicking on the gun button and on the 3rd try it worked on the doors in the back - then the moving banner was working. I hope this might help you.